# How to auto-generate multiple maps with different features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, maps, tools, atlas

Anyone can explain me how can i auto-generate multiple maps with different variablies using Atlas tool in QGIS?
So i have only 1 layer which consists of 10+ features, and i want select some of that features to auto-generate different maps, with different ranges too for each one (e.g 0-100 ; 100 - 500 ; 500 - 1000).

At moment im just be able to do one by one, but anyone know how to generate in one step?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the documentation here :

http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#atlas-generation

and the example in

http://nathanw.net/2014/09/23/qgis-atlas-on-non-geometry-tables/

Comment: This would be considered a link-only answer, which is generally discouraged. It is best to at least outline or summarize the information contained at the link in the answer itself. Otherwise, should the link become broken in the future, the answer would be useless.

Comment: there is a detailed example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114746/how-to-auto-generate-map-images-with-different-styles-in-qgis